# Transliterate from Cirillyc to Latin

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, transliteration

I want a directory to be created in Content folder of Web layer when new products category is created, but since categories names are in Cirillyc and Cirillyc in path is not good, it might be wise to create a folder with transliterated name. I tried UnidecodeSharpFork but it's producing different symbols (like ') which are also not good for directory name. Are there any other options in this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing transliteration map *malually*:

```
// Capital letters should be transliterated by the same scheme
public class CaseInsensitiveComparer: IEqualityComparer<char> {
  public bool Equals(char left, char right) {
    return char.ToUpperInvariant(left) == char.ToUpperInvariant(right);
  }
  public int GetHashCode(char value) {
    return char.ToUpperInvariant(value).GetHashCode();
  }
}

...

// implement map manually 
private static Dictionary<char, String> map = 
  new Dictionary<char, string>(new CaseInsensitiveComparer()) {
    {'а', "a" },
    {'б', "b" },
    ...
    {'я', "ya" },
};
```

then use it:

```
string source = "My string (Моя Строка)";

string result = string.Concat(source.Select(c => {
  string st;

  if (map.TryGetValue(c, out st))
    return char.IsUpper(c) ? st.ToUpperInvariant() : st;
  else
    return c.ToString();
}));
```

Test

```
// My string (Moya Stroka) 
Console.Write(result);
```